# How to have a mp4 start playing when it's modal opens?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have a video beautifully opening up in a modal (not using plugin or Bootstrap). But when I click to open that modal, I would like the video to start playing.

This is my code thus far:

```
<div id="middle_circle_wrap" class="circle_wrap">
    <a href="#openVideo"><img src="images/video_icon_oval.png" height="240px" width="240px" id="middle_circle" class="circle"></a>
    <span id="middle_text">Meet Dawn Dause Video</span>
</div>

<div id="openVideo" class="videoDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <video width="640" height="400" controls id="dawn_video">
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

From a previous thread on here I implemented this code:

```
var p = document.getElementById('middle_circle_wrap');
var v = document.getElementById('dawn_video');

    v.addEventListener(
        'play', 
        function() { 
            v.play();
        }, 
        false);

    p.onclick = function() {
        if (v.paused) {
            v.play();
        } else {
            v.pause();
        }

        return false;
    };
```

The video plays (can hear the audio) but it stops the modal from opening. I am not sure why it cannot do both? Any ideas how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/tt5t893n/

This Fiddle is the best I can do for an example because I am not sure how to link it to a real video and don't really want to. But, you can see the modal is prevented from opening when the JS is activated, but if you comment it out, it opens.

Comment: Need CSS and a live demo would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are using modal by bootstrap

```
$( "#openVideo" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    v.play();
});
```

Comment: Since I am clearly using pure JavaScript, can you give this in JavaScript instead of JQuery? Is it possible in pure JavaScript instead of JQuery?

Comment: Oh I see now where you say "if you are using modal by bootstrap". I am *not* using modal by bootstrap. I made my own modal.